# how to add WSP file in central admin through Management Shell

Tags: powershell, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2013, wsp

I am adding wsp file as it already exist now I need to update it..

Its giving me a error message on management shell that

A solution with the same name and id already exist.

I am writing this command in management shell.

```
 Add-SPSolution "c:\Deploy\WSP\{file name}.wsp"
```

Like this

`Add-SPSolution "c:\Deploy\WSP\SharePointProject2.wsp`"

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways you can achieve this:

1. Use 'Update-SPSolution' Or
2. Remove solution using 'Remove-SPSolution' and add again using
   'Add-SPSolution'

Comment: Update-SPSolution –Identity SharePointProject2.wsp   trying this not working  with that I am  also trying        Update-SPSolution –Identity SharePointProject2.wsp–LiteralPath “D:\SharePointProject2.wsp”–GACDeployment   this is also not working... with that I am trying

Comment: Remove-SPSolution "SharePointProject2.wsp" also not working... after retracting it still not working Akshay...

Comment: May I know what is the issue? Could you please explain it? have you tried "-force" attribute with Remove-SPSolution?